# how to show all spin groups are double covers?

Tags: spin-geometry

If that's the definition, then how do we know *double* covers of $SO(n)$ exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of covering theory. Its [central theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Galois_correspondence) says that for a reasonable topological space (like the manifold $\operatorname{SO}(n)$) path-connected coverings correspond in a certain way to subgroups of the fundamental group, and the degree of such a covering corresponds to the index of the subgroup. 
The fundamental group of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ hence the trivial group is an index 2 subgroup. The mentioned theorem now implies the existence of a (essentially unique) path-connected double covering.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference that explains this in more detail?

Comment: @Alex Covering theory is discussed in Chapter 1.3 of Hatchers “Algebraic topology”. A very detailed exposition is given in Part VIII of these [lecture notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=111368).